# Apache2 install failing with code 127

Tags: server, apache2

I am trying to install a LAMP stack on my Ubuntu 18.04 virtual box. The box is basically a fresh install, although I am running Geth, which is an Ethereum client.

when I run the command `sudo apt-get install apache2`, I receive the error that the installation failed with code 127. There is nothing in the apache error logs telling me why  this installation failed. Here is my error log:

```
Setting up apache2 (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.5) ...
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-01-16 22:47:47 UTC; 7ms ago
  Process: 3978 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 8972 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 16 22:47:47 EthereumDaemon systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 16 22:47:47 EthereumDaemon apachectl[3978]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apachectl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
Jan 16 22:47:47 EthereumDaemon apachectl[3978]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 16 22:47:47 EthereumDaemon apachectl[3978]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 16 22:47:47 EthereumDaemon systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jan 16 22:47:47 EthereumDaemon systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 16 22:47:47 EthereumDaemon systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
```

When running the suggested command `systemctl status apache2.service` for details, I just receive the above error information.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the message `/usr/sbin/apache2: not found` it would look like the `apache2-bin` package is missing or improperly installed

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt install --fix-broken` can help...

Comment: @pa4080 unfortunately that didn't resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you got the answer
i think you have might delete dir from /usr/sbin/apache
code = 127 start service path not found
just do
'''
==> `sudo apt install -reinstall apache2-bin`
'''
it will fix
**if you are running nginx also together then change port of apache from `/etc/apach2/port.conf` file from 80 to what ever you want it will run**

Comment: correct command is ```sudo apt install --reinstall apache2-bin```.